# Observable.of not compiling if I don't import * as Rx from "rxjs"

Tags: rxjs

I am wondering why the following code doesn't compile

```
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
userSignedIn$: Observable<boolean>; //naming convention for Streams has $ in the end.
this.userSignedIn$ = Observable.of(false)
```

I see error - `Property of doesn't exist on type 'typeof Observable'`

But it works if I add the following line

```
import * as Rx from "rxjs"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the `of` function doesn't exist on the `Observable` prototype. You have to add it by doing `import "rxjs/add/observable/of";`. When you do `import * as Rx from "rxjs"` I bet it pulls in `import "rxjs/add/observable/of";` which makes it work. Depending on your version of rxjs you could instead do `import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';` (5.5+ I believe).